# how to update a stored data in localstorage?

Tags: vue.js, local-storage

suppose I have DATa
and I stored it in localstorage:

```
 var serializedObject = JSON.stringify(response.data.data);
        localStorage.setItem("serializedObject",serializedObject);
        console.log(localStorage.getItem('serializedObject'));
        originalObject.value = JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem('serializedObject'));
        logInDetails.value = originalObject.value;
```

and this is the console of logInDetails:

```
[ { "id": 1, "user_id": 2, "user_image": "49914692_2274892909503020_6776713521204822016_n.jpg", "first_name": "Michaelsdsdsd", "middle_name": "Millares", "last_name": "Corral", "suffix": "jr", "birth_date": "0000-00-00", "email_address": "haifasgd05@gmail.com", "phone_number": 9526487987, "civil_status": "single", "occupation": "student", "street": "purok 2", "brgy_name": "busay", "city_municipality": "daraga", "province": "albay", "sex": "male", "username": "sadf", "password": "a", "date_created": "0000-00-00", "date_archieve": "0000-00-00" } ]
```

is it possible to update or change the value that is stored in localstorage?
beacause if I update directly to the logIndetails. the data in localstorage won't be update so.

Comment: Yes, to update it you need to seriale the object and call localStorage.setItem again. Local storage is saved by value, not by ref thus to update it you need to update the value manually